# Unable to load assembly found in the GAC

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0, t4

I'm trying to load in an assembly that is present at C:\Windows\assembly\ and is called
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating   (version 9.0.0.0)

This is the command in PowerShell 2.0 I'm using

```
$inputfile = 'Hello.tt'
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating") | 
   Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating") $inputfile
```

The error I get is 
**default.ps1:Cannot find type [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating] make sure the assembly containing the type is loaded.**

Edit: I use the same method to load in other Microsoft assemblies like Smo which are also registered in the cache, so I wonder if there's another issue around this assembly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here doesn't appear to be the assembly load.  I verified that the `LoadWithPartialName` method does load the assembly in question.

The problem is that your `New-Object` call is being passed a namespace and not a type.  You need to instead pass it a type name inside the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating` namespace.